# How to Check Web service response is a valid json or not programmatically in android?

Tags: android, json, web-services, rest, web

I am using web services in my application. I use REST services. When I call the web service I get a 200 Response code and correct json response too. But sometimes I get a 200 response code along with an non-json response. So before parsing I need to check whether its a valid json or not. Pls help me.

Comment: Below two answers are fine to go with , but u need to fix the code on server side or if ur doing it purposefully send json as error message , so that u dont have put this additional check in each server call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use try catch block. Like this:

```
    try {
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("yourjsonstring");
      }
    catch(JSONException j) {
    System.out.println("Not a JSON");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check Json String with the help of following method,

```
public boolean isJSONValid(String json)
{
   try 
   {
    new JSONObject(json);
        return true;
   } 
   catch(JSONException ex) 
   { 
       return false;
   }
}
```